# Bircher muesli: how to make oats soak liquid

Tags: milk, breakfast, oats

Recently I've been making bircher muesli for breakfast, but oat flakes never seem to soak much liquid. They remain mostly a separate layer in a milk soup (separate from milk and from each other). And I'm looking to achieve more of a rice pudding consistency I've seen in a few cafes serving their own bircher muesli.

I use 1:1 liquid/oats ration (by volume), which seems to be the recommended one in most online recipes, whole milk, standard rolled oats and leave the mixture covered in the fridge for 12 hours. Is there anything I'm not doing right? (I'll give quick oats a try next, perhaps that will help)

Comment: What do you mean by "never seem to soak"? Are you simply soaking traditional oats in milk, or are you cooking them?

Comment: You mention using quick oats next time, what kind of oats are you using now?

Comment: I added more information to the post (simply soaking, standard rolled oats, 12 hours) It did occur to me that some bircher muesli sold in cafes could be partly cooked, so perhaps that's the answer.

Answer (score 1):

I've never made this, but have seen it on display in Switzerland breakfast buffets. I would think you may get a more absorbent oat flake if you were to try the par-cooked variety (quick oats).

Comment: Not that that would make better müsli. Just, more soggy